# Check if the input exists in a file

Tags: python, loops, file, if-statement, while-loop

Hi I am trying to check:

- If the user determined input exists in the file and if it does then find the line number of that input in the file.
- If it doesn't then tell the user that the input doesn't exist.
  My while loop works fine, and it finds the line number of the string if it exists. However my if statement has a logic error, it always passes the statement to else. I am new to python, if someone can help that would be great!

```
import sys
f=open("/Users/emirmac/Desktop/file.txt","r")
count=1
l=0
inputWord=input("Enter a word: ")
while(l)!="":
    l=f.readline()
    Line=l.split()
    if inputWord in Line:
        print("Line number",count,":",l)

    count+=1

f.close()

if inputWord in Line:
    print(inputWord,"is the",count, "most common word.")
    
else:
    print("Sorry,",inputWord,"is not one of the 4000 most common words.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop keeps going even after it found `inputWord`, overwriting the current value. if you do `print(inputWord)` after the while loop it will always be the very last line of your text document.

Adding a `break` statement will exit the loop as soon as it finds the word.

```
while(l)!="":
    l=f.readline()
    Line=l.split()
    if inputWord in Line:
        print("Line number",count,":",l)
        break

    count+=1
    
if inputWord in Line:
    print(inputWord,"is the",count, "most common word.")
    
else:
    print("Sorry,",inputWord,"is not one of the 4000 most common words.")
```

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing exactly what is contained in the file, it's hard to say exactly what you need. Does the file just have one word per line and are all lines unique?

Regardless, it looks like the problem is that once you get to the `if inputWord in Line: print("Line number",count,":",l)` you don't actually break out of the loop, so you should add a `break` statement right below your print statement there. In other words, you correctly locate the line but then you keep looping and `Line` gets updated, so by the time you get to the final check `inputWord` is no longer in `Line` (unless it were coincidentally in the last line of the file if that makes sense. It's also unclear why you wanted to put that if statement in there anyway. See if something like this is what you were trying to do.

```
import sys
f=open("/Users/emirmac/Desktop/file.txt","r")
count=1
l=0
inputWord=input("Enter a word: ")
while(l)!="":
    l=f.readline()
    Line=l.split()
    if inputWord in Line:
        print(inputWord,"is the",count, "most common word.")
        break
    count+=1
else:
    print("Sorry,",inputWord,"is not one of the 4000 most common words.")

f.close()
```